# ASP.NET GridView: Confirm button click postback with jQueryUI dialog

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, linkbutton, gridviewrow

I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out.  I've looked all around have yet to find an example that will help me.  I have a feeling that I'm super close on this...

I have an asp:gridview with a linkbutton at the end of each row.  I need to do a confirmation dialog before running the onrowcommand.  Here is the code I have to do it... What am I missing?

```
function confirmProcessing(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#dialog")
        .dialog({
            title: "Confirm Transaction",
            buttons: {
                "Process": function () {                                        
                    $("#dialog").dialog('close');

                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                    return false;
                }
            },
            close: function() {                            
                return false;
            },
            modal: true,
            appendTo: "form"

        })
        .parent()
        .css('z-index', '1005');

}
```

**aspx code**

```
<div class="row">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ccList" CssClass="table table-striped table-responsive" ShowHeader="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="ccList_OnRowDataBound" OnRowCommand="ccList_OnRowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Street" ItemStyle-CssClass="Street" HeaderText="Street"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ZipCode" ItemStyle-CssClass="ZipCode" HeaderText="Zip"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MB4P" ItemStyle-CssClass="MB4P" HeaderText="MB4P"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MB4S" ItemStyle-CssClass="MB4S" HeaderText="MB4S"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BAL" ItemStyle-CssClass="BAL" HeaderText="BAL"/>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnProcess" OnClientClick="confirmProcessing(event);" Text="Process Payment" CommandName="Process" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>    
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>

<div id="dialog" style="display:none">        
    <b>Are you sure you want to process this record?</b>
</div>
```

**OnRowCommand code**

```
protected void ccList_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Process")
    {
        //Do the processing stuff here after confirm dialog.
    }        
}
```

If I remove the preventDefault it fires through to the OnRowCommand which is expected.  I just don't know how to get the Process button in the modal dialog to fire off the command... what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The aspx code is not showing up.  I do not get an editor toolbar when trying to edit it so I am at a loss on why it won't pass the format validation if I change anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnClientClick` property of the LinkButton can be set in the `RowDataBound` event handler of the GridView, with the `UniqueID` of the button as the argument to `confirmProcessing`:

```
protected void ccList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton btnProcess = e.Row.FindControl("btnProcess") as LinkButton;
        btnProcess.OnClientClick = string.Format("return confirmProcessing('{0}');", btnProcess.UniqueID);
        ...
    }
}
```

The Javascript event handler can then be modified as follows:

```
function confirmProcessing(btnUniqueID) {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "Confirm Transaction",
        buttons: {
            "Process": function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                __doPostBack(btnUniqueID, '');
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                return false;
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            return false;
        },
        modal: true,
        appendTo: "form"

    }).parent().css('z-index', '1005');

    return false;
}
```

When the LinkButton is clicked, the dialog is displayed and the function returns `false` to cancel the initial postback. If the dialog is then closed by clicking on `Process`, `__doPostBack` is called with the `UniqueID` of the LinkButton to cause the postback.

**Note**: I thought that the `UniqueID` could be retrieved in client code with the help of the `name` attribute. It works for the Button control but not for the LinkButton. That is why I suggest setting the `OnClientClick` property in code-behind.

Comment: I didn't realize that I couldn't get the UniqueID of the LinkButton.  That is why the editor was giving me an error saying it didn't recognize my btnProcess.UniqueId reference.  I couldn't not figure out why and it really threw me off.  I will test this right now and see if it work.  PS: Thanks for fixing up the code in my formatting above.

Comment: That did it.  Awesome.  Thanks so much.